# Definition Query - Length of Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, definition-query

Is it possible to create a definition query that will return a subset of values based on a specific field length?

I only want string values where length is less than or equal to 2 characters.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact data source format, since different source workspaces have differing functions.

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like this

Select * FROM

LEN(FIELD_NAME) <= 2

I just tested this in ArcMap 10.5 and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In ArcMap 10.3.1, I had to change LEN to CHAR_LENGTH.

```
Select * FROM

CHAR_LENGTH(FIELD_NAME) <= 2
```